# Creation of table and insertion within the same procedure in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to create a table and then insert some values in it within the same procedure in pl/sql. I tried to run the following query without success:

```
create or replace Procedure insertval8(id_no in number,e_name in char)
is
 begin
 execute immediate 'create table edu2(id number(20), name char(12))';
 insert into edu2 values(&id_no,&e_name);
 end;
```

displays

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
5/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
5/13     PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exists
```

The error persists until I remove the insert code.

Comment: Why are you creating the table within the procedure in the first place? That should never be necessary; for a start, you can only ever call the procedure once as subsequent calls would error.

Answer (score 4):

The procedure cannot be compiled because the table is not present at compile time.

Wrap the insert in execute immediate also, or use a global temporary table (generaly the preferred solution for temporary data).

```
create or replace procedure insertval8 (id   in number,
                                        name in char  )
is
begin

  execute immediate 'create table edu2(id number(20), name char(12))';
  execute immediate 'insert into  edu2(id, name) values (:1, :2)'
              using id, name;
end;
```

Comment: hello sir thanks for your suggestion  i did that already but again it is showing error like
    create or replace procedure add3()
    as
    id1 integer;
    id2 char ;
    begin
    execute immediate 'create table sas(id integer,name char(20))';
    execute immediate 'insert into sas (id,name)values(id1,id2)';
    end;
    /
     now the error is in insert statement pointing to (id1,id2) columns not allowed here 
    please help

Comment: @user3245451, re-read David's answer - you haven't specified the bind variables correctly for your insert.